# Could not find com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.0.0.300

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

```
Could not find com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.0.0.300.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/huawei/agconnect/agcp/1.0.0.300/agcp-1.0.0.300.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/huawei/agconnect/agcp/1.0.0.300/agcp-1.0.0.300.jar
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/huawei/agconnect/agcp/1.0.0.300/agcp-1.0.0.300.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/huawei/agconnect/agcp/1.0.0.300/agcp-1.0.0.300.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

I am following this document but still facing issue.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSAnalyticsKit/index.html#2

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you are missed to add application gradle configurations.

Try after adding these lines on your gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {      
        maven { url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.0.300'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {  
        maven { url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
}
```

Comment: My Android Studio is extremly slow in syncing and building the app since I added these dependencies to grade. Did you also had the problems?

Comment: No I never had that problem

Comment: @JulianSchweppe to speed up the build make sure the Huawei maven repo url is on the last position in your main build.gradle file (after google, jcenter and all the others)

Answer (score 1):

Though your environment is built based on the codelab of Analytics Kit, but the AppGallery Connect plug-in is not configured correctly, so you cannot find it. Configure it by referring to the [guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSPreparation/index.html#6) at the link.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the current version; it's more alike this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://developer.huawei.com/repo/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.0.300"
    }
}
```