# Could not resolve com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.0.300

Tags: android, maven, gradle, huawei-mobile-services

need help how to fix problem of HMS SDK.

```
> Could not get resource
> 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/com/huawei/agconnect/agcp/1.6.0.300/agcp-1.6.0.300.pom'.
>             > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/com/huawei/agconnect/agcp/1.6.0.300/agcp-1.6.0.300.pom'.
> Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

build.gradle:

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()  
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }    
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}    
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

This may be because the gradle is in offline mode or the current network is limited.  Therefore, you are advised to check the gradle configuration and network settings.

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
        google() 
        jcenter() 
        // Configure the Maven repository address for the HMS Core SDK. 
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'} 
    } 
    dependencies { 
        ... 
        // Add the AppGallery Connect plugin configuration. You are advised to use the latest plugin version. 
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.0.300' 
    } 
} 
 
allprojects { 
    repositories { 
        google() 
        jcenter() 
        // Configure the Maven repository address for the HMS Core SDK. 
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'} 
    } 
}
```

For details about how to configure the build.gradle file, kindly refer to [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSPreparation/index.html#6).

Comment: now it's working, looks like network issue

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here

[Could not find com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.0.0.300](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813107/could-not-find-com-huawei-agconnectagcp1-0-0-300)

"Looks like you are missed to add application gradle configurations.

Try after adding these lines on your gradle file

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {      
        maven { url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.0.300'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {  
        maven { url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
}
```

"

Or one of the other options there..

Comment: you need to use `https` `https://developer.huawei.com/repo`